# nuxt-child doesn't render the parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

My folder structure is like this:

```
|-profile
|-- index.vue
|-- address/index.vue
```

And then I do `<nuxt-child />` which doesn't render the content of `profile/index.vue`! It just loads a whole new route. Please help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Folder structure above will create a whole new route, instead of a nested one.

You can see exact same structure in Nuxt.js [Routing](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#basic-routes) documentation example.

Examples of [nested routes](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#nested-routes) are also available in documentation

In your case, in order to render nested route in `<nuxt-child>`, following structure will work:

```
|-pages/
|--| profile/
|-----| address.vue
|-----| index.vue
|--| profile.vue
```

And `<nuxt-child>` tag should be inside `profile.vue` page. This way `profile/index.vue` will be rendered when user navigates to `/profile` and `address.vue` will be rendered when user navigates to `/profile/address`.

Comment: not working for me, how would you do this if your profile was _profile meaning dynamic

Comment: You'd do the same, but with `_` (underscore) for both `.vue` file and folder. See examples in [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#dynamic-nested-routes)

Comment: @aBiscuit I'm using the same approach but when `keep-alive` is enabled, it will cause the `profile` page to cache and show other sub-pages ( like `address.vue` in your case ) and doesn't show the `profile/index.vue` content. Any ideas how to tackle this issue?